# How do you pad a string in Scala with a character for missing elements in a Vector?

Tags: scala

If I have a sparse list of numbers:

```
Vector(1,3,7,8,9)
```

and I need to generate a string of a fixed size which replaces the 'missing' numbers with a given character that might look like this:

```
1.3...789
```

How would I do this in Scala?

Comment: do you mean 1.3...7.8.9?

Comment: I think the OP wants a period for each missing number, so the periods in the example represent 2, 4, 5 and 6.

Comment: The desire is to represent each missing digit with a character. In this case, 2, 4, 5, 6 are this missing numbers and should be represented with a character. If instead, 3, 5, and 7 were the missing numbers, the desired string would be 12.4.6.89.

Comment: Are there at most 10? I.e is it a single digit each time?

Comment: Yes, only a single digit. If the range beyond 1-9 is required, I would imagine would use a-z (e.g., like base-16 digits).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure the range of the integers.  So I'm assuming that they may not fit into a char and used a string.  Try this:

```
val v = Vector(1,3,7,8,9)
val fixedStr = ( v.head to v.last )
                   .map( i => if (v.contains(i)) i.toString else "." )
                   .mkString
```

If you are only dealing with single digits then you may change the strings to chars in the above.

-- edit --

ok, so I couldn't help myself and addressed the issue of sparse vector and wanted to change it to use the sliding function.  Figured it does no good sitting on my PC so sharing here:

```
v.sliding(2)
  .map( (seq) => if (seq.size == 2) seq else seq ++ seq )  //normalize window to size 2
  .foldLeft( new StringBuilder )( (sb, seq) =>             //fold into stringbuilder
    seq match { case Seq(a,b) => sb.append(a).append( "." * (b - a - 1) ) } )
  .append( v.last )
  .toString
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is using `sliding` and pattern matching:

```
def mkNiceString(v: Vector[Int]) = {
   v.sliding(2).map{
     case Seq(a) => ""
     case Seq(a,b) => 
       val gap = b-a; 
       a.toString + (if(gap>1) "." * (gap-1) else "")
   }.mkString + v.last
}
```

In the REPL:

```
scala> mkNiceString(Vector(1,3,7,8,9,11))
res22: String = 1.3...789.11
```

Comment: mkNiceString(Vector(2)) -> scala.MatchError

Comment: marios, I really like your use of sliding here.   This begins to look like a fold to me; perhaps a fold into a StringBuffer.  Anyway, Scala is awesome!

Answer (score 1):

If the vector is sparse, this will be more efficient than checking the range between the first and the last number.

```
def padVector(numbers: Vector[Int], placeHolder: String) = {
  def inner(nums: Vector[Int], prevNumber: Int, acc: String) : String = 
    if (nums.length == 0) acc
    else (nums.head - prevNumber) match {
      // the difference is 1 -> no gap between this and previous number
      case 1 => inner(nums.tail, nums.head, acc + nums.head)
      // gap between numbers -> add placeholder x times
      case x => inner(nums.tail, nums.head, acc + (placeHolder * (x-1)) + nums.head)
    }

  if (numbers.length == 0) ""
  else inner(numbers.tail, numbers.head, numbers.head.toString)
}
```

Output:

```
scala> padVector(Vector(1,3,7,8,9), ".")
res4: String = 1.3...789
```